# I want to increase the total of a large selection of cells by 5% -- is there a formula for this in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a table for our budget this year; I need to show an estimate budget for next year with a 5% increase all round. Can I do this with a formula as it is going to take hours to do the maths for each cell (approx200 cells!!!)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **[Array Function feature](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions)** to apply the calculation to all the source cells in one step.

In the following example, i assume that the source cells are in the cell range A1:C3.

In the first cell of the target range (holding the result of the 5% increase; in my example: A6:C8), insert the following formula **and press** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> **to enter it** (adapt the decimal separator if required):

```
= A1:C3 + (A1:C3 * 0,05)
```

[image]

Entering a formula using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> will make LO Calc to interpret it as array function. There are some special point to notice when working with array formulas; the most important thing to remember is that you can edit the result of an array formula only by editing the complete array. So, to edit the formula, you will have to select the complete result array first; and you'll have to finish editing the array formula using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Anyway, after <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the result will look like this:

[image]

This way, you can calculate on multiple cells with a single formula.